# CarPlay remote Image to UIImage

Tags: swift, xcode, carplay

I am trying to get remote images to show for Apple CarPlay.

I know I need to make an extension as it does not work by default.

I have tried to add the following and I get **No exact matches in call to initializer** Which I don't know what that means or how to fix.

```
extension UIImage {

    func imageFromBase64(_ base64: String) -> UIImage? {
        if let url = URL(string: base64), let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
            return UIImage(data: data)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

```
 let item = CPListItem(text: station.name,
                                    detailText: station.name,
                                    image:  station.imageurl.imageFromBase64()
              )
```

Comment: `station.imageurl.imageFromBase64()`, so I guess that `station.imageurl` is a String. So does `String` have a method called `imageFromBase64()`? No. You added on for `UIImage` instances, and it has a parameter. Plus, this is a sync code, so it will freeze the current thread with `Data(contentsOf:)`.

Comment: @Larme The imagery just points to a URL where the image is hosted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your station image url is probably a `String` or a `URL` type, however your extension is for a UIImage type so there is a type mismatch.

You might be better off just creating a simple function rather than an extension

```
func imageFromBase64(_ base64: String) -> UIImage? {
    if let url = URL(string: base64),
       let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
        return UIImage(data: data)
    }
    return nil
}

let item = CPListItem(text: station.name,
                      detailText: station.name,
                      image: imageFromBase64(station.imageurl))
```

If you do want to make it a UIImage extension, I think you need to initialize a UIImage with a URL so this is an option:

```
extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(url: URL?) {
        
        guard let url = url,
              let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
        else {
            self.init()
            return
        }
         
        self.init(data: data)
    }
}

let url = URL(string: station.imageurl)
let stationImage = UIImage(url: url)

let item = CPListItem(text: station.name,
                      detailText: station.name,
                      image: stationImage)
```

However, this will block the main thread while loading so I suggest looking at the comment on your [previous question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71657030/1619193) by a user called `fruitcoder`

He shows how to load data asynchronously for CarPlay. Here is the [code](https://gist.github.com/fruitcoder/4ccd2d2f52d12e2199228516e62cc693#file-carplaypost_carplay-extensions1-swift) and he has another [article](https://medium.com/br-next/launching-br-radio-on-carplay-audio-8baab824b932#fd31) for the same.